# Error deserializing Json to object when including “é è à” characters

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization

I tried using DataContractJsonSerializer to deserialize the JSON string to object. All works fine until the JSON string contains some French characters, such as `é è à`. It will throw the exception:

> There was an error deserializing the object of type **. The token '"' was expected but found 'é'.

Is there anybody know to resolve it?

```
{ "features": [ { "id": "0c50cdc5-da97-45be-aad2-ad1433d8e285LastEditedFeature", "wkt": "", "fieldValues": [ { "Key": "formeID", "Value": "1" }, { "Key": "calqueID", "Value": "1" }, { "Key": "featureID", "Value": "0c50cdc5-da97-45be-aad2-ad1433d8e285" }, { "Key": "Name", "Value": "ABCDé" } ] } ] }
```

I'm afraid that maybe it's caused by the é in "ABCDé" string.

Comment: You may be missing quotes around your string. What does [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) say about it?

Comment: Or perhaps a charset problem. Check if your serialized stuff is UTF-8 and that you deserialize it as UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error would seem to indicate that you are missing a quote at the end of your string?

To better help us, could you post the JSON that works and doesn't work?

Comment: the JSON string:
 { "features": [ { "id": "0c50cdc5-da97-45be-aad2-ad1433d8e285LastEditedFeature", "wkt": "", "fieldValues": [ { "Key": "formeID", "Value": "1" }, { "Key": "calqueID", "Value": "1" }, { "Key": "featureID", "Value": "0c50cdc5-da97-45be-aad2-ad1433d8e285" }, { "Key": "Name", "Value": "ABCDé" } ] } ] } 
the code:
DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(type);
MemoryStream jsonStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(jsonString));
resultObject = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(jsonStream);
jsonStream.Close();
it works if the Encoding is UTF8.

Comment: "it works if the Encoding is UTF8" What other encoding would a sane person use?

Comment: @CodesInChaos – [I can see](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35676723/2392157) this issue in [tag:.net-3.5] even with UTF-8. I found no way around it so far.

Answer (score 0):

**Besides the accepted answer, there seems to be an issue in [.net-3.5](/questions/tagged/.net-3.5) JSON implementation.** Plain **UTF-8** JSON serialization and deserialization in [.net-3.5](/questions/tagged/.net-3.5) leads to this error on proof-string shown below. But if you switch the project to [.net-4.0](/questions/tagged/.net-4.0) or higher, the issue immediately disappears.

```c#
string proofString = "";
for (int i = 1; i <= 0xffff; i++) {
    if (i >= 0xd800 && i < 0xe000) continue; // skip code points not belonging to UTF-8
    proofString += Strings.ChrW(i);
}
```